# How to "IF" and "NEXT" in R to skip rows in a dataframe column?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R with "N" rows that looks like this:

[image]

My idea is write a loop in R (perhaps containing "IF" and "NEXT") that will skip the next row with an ID whenever if finds a Value = 0 after a Value = 1. For instance, in the case of ID1 I'd only save up to its 4th row (Value = 1) and skip the remaining (Value = 0) and then go to ID10 where I'd save up to its 2nd row (Value = 1) and skip all others and go to ID2 where I'd save only the first (Value = 1) and skip the others and then go to ID3 and so forth so on.

Currently, I have something that looks like this loop:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can accomplish that?

Thanks a bunch,
Diego.

Comment: Please don't post images, instead use `dput` to show the example.  Can you also show the expected output.

Comment: @akrun - I'm getting it too - bizarre cut-and-paste errors when taking code from SO comments. Non-printing space characters... weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'IDs', we get the index of the first maximum value in 'value' (`which.max`), find the sequence of it (i.e. if we get 5 as the first 1, then it will be 1:5), wrap it with `.I` to get the row index, extract the column (`$V1`) and subset the dataset.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[seq(which.max(value))], by = IDS]$V1]
```

It is not clear if a particular 'IDs' have only 0s for 'value'.  If we need to skip that 'IDs', use an `if` condition

```
setDT(df1)[df1[, if(any(value!=0)) .I[seq(which.max(value))], by = IDs]$V1]
```

---

To understand the syntax we can split up the process

```
setDT(df1) #converts the `data.frame` to `data.table`
```

Now, we can do the process to get the rowids.  In the below code, we group by 'IDs', get the index of the first element that is 1 for 'value' (`which.max(value)`), then do the sequence (`seq(...)`), and find the row index in the whole dataset (`.I[...]`).

```
df1[, .I[seq(which.max(value))] , by = IDs]
```

The above a dataset with columns 'IDs' and a default column 'V1' for the row index (as we didn't specify the column name)

If we are extracting that column, use `$V1` or `[["V1"]]`

```
i1 <- df1[, .I[seq(which.max(value))] , by = IDs]$V1
```

The row index ('i1') object is used to subset the rows of the initial dataset

```
df1[i1]
```

Comment: Hi! First off, thanks for your promptly response. Second, no IDs have 0s, so we are good here. A couple of things, though: with your solution I wouldn't need to use a for loop, right? Second, I still don't get what you meant by "extract the column ($V1) and subset the dataset." 


I have two columns as you can see, (IDS and Value) and 25 rows. What's $V1 in my case? How is the subsetting done?

Comment: @DiegoMenezes  I have updated the post with some explanation.  Yes, you don't need to use any `for` loop and would be very efficient.  The extracting part is explained in the solution.

Comment: Hey akrun. Thanks for getting back to me on this. I've a day packed with meetings all day long, but will test your solution as soon as I can a get back to you.

Comment: @DiegoMenezes  Thanks, no problem.  Glad that you responded.

Comment: akrun, just tested your solution and it works perfectly. Multiple thanks for your help with this.